# Separate elements inside array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have react property as array and I want to split those elements with `-`. I tried to use .split('-') but didn't work.

```
<Application
  property={['name', 'lastName']}
/>
```

So, name and last name should be:
Name - Last Name

Inside Applications:

```
return (
                  <div key={`propName-${value}`}>
                    <span>{value}</span>
                    {' '} // the space is for: Name (space) LastName (space)
                  </div>
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Since we need `['name', '-', 'lastName']`, we can simply add it using [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.

```
const data = ['name', 'lastName'];
data.splice(1, 0, '-')
console.log(data);  // ["name", "-", "lastName"]
```

---

Use [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

> The `join()` method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated by commas or a specified separator string.

```
<Application
  property={['name', 'lastName'].join('-')}
/>
```

Comment: I used too. Didn't work. Invalid 'property' of type 'string'.,expected an array is the error

Comment: @alar This error means you need to pass an Array for the props `property`, so do you need `['name', '-', 'lastName']` ?

Comment: Yes I need like that, but when I do that, I'm not getting '-', just Name and Last Name

Answer (score 0):

Update:

In your component add this code:

```
// In your component
const [firstName, lastName] = property;

return (
  <div key={`propName-${value}`}>
    <span>
      {`${firstName} - ${lastName}`}   
    </span>                
  </div>
)
```

or

```
// In your component
const fullName = property.join(' - ');

return (
  <div key={`propName-${value}`}>
    <span>
      {fullName}   
    </span>               
  </div>
)
```

---

You can do it like this:

```
const arr = ['name', 'lastName'];

const fullName = arr.join(' - ');
```

Or use this directly in your component with `property`

Comment: Same result:  Invalid 'property' of type 'string'.,expected an array is the error

Comment: Please, show the code of ```<Application />``` component

Comment: I can show that:
```
return (
                  <div key={`${val}`}>
                    <span>{val}</span>
                    {' '} // here are the space that separe Name (space) LastName (space)
                  </div>
                )
```